# Can Apollo graphql be used with Nextjs without having to install react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

An ApolloProvider wraps an app:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
</ApolloProvider>
```

The problem is, in nextjs you can declare route components in the pages folder WITHOUT having to add them to App.js

Which leads to the error "Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. "

Can Apollo be used in these components with the native Nextjs way of handling routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did with mine, make a separate folder I called it apollo folder just like this:

[image]

then inside that folder create a file name it whatever you want then put this code or whatever code for you apollo client

apollo/ apolloClient.js

```
 import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";
    import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
    import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
    import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
    import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
    
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: "http://localhost:5000",
    });
    
    const authLink = setContext(() => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
      return {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
        },
      };
    });
    
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    
    export default client;
```

You have to export the client or what I did with mine and go to the _app.js:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import client from "../apollo/apolloClient";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

We have imported the client from the apolloClient.js file that we just created and exported the client

Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Ok I'm dumb, I had the ApolloProvider in index.js wrapping App.js
I moved ApolloProvider  to _app.js like in your example and it all works now, thank you very much sir

Comment: It's fine, you started learning reactjs and convert to nextjs too?

Comment: Yes, it's my first project in Next ever and I really like it :)

Comment: Goodluckk, me too Im trying to convert my project to nextjs

Comment: Cool add me on discord bro alexh#3397

Comment: Ok will check bro